# Can't install any python package from the python command prompt

Tags: python, shell, installation, package

I am trying to install some python packages from the python shell but I get syntaxError. I am using  python 3.4.3 which supposed to come with pip installed and I can see pip3 pip3.4, pip, easy_install, and easy_install-3.4 under scripts but whenever I run the command in the shell I get syntax error. 
Am I not supposed to use the python shell for package installation? I am using windows 8.1 if that would explain something. I tried these commands:
pip install packageName --- got syntaxError with this message:File '' line 1, pip install(with a mark at last l in install). easy_install packageName generated the same error message but with the mark at the last letter in the packagename, i double checked all spellings but I can't seem to see what the problem is.  How can I install packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you are just to use the Windows terminal for pip package installations.
If that does not work, ensure that you have installed Python properly following this guide [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).

Comment: I got it to work by adding my scripts path to my environment variables. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I not supposed to use the python shell for package installation?

No.  Commands like `pip` are to be run on the operating system command line (i.e., the "DOS prompt" on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Click Windows(button)+R then type `cmd`. In there type `pip -V`, what version does it show?

If you get `pip 6.1.1 from C:\Python32\lib\site-packages <python 3.4>` (depending on your directory) then you're good, simply make your installations from there.